# Como fazer para selecionar tudo menos o top X no MYSQL

Tags: mysql

Estou programando um projeto pessoal de agendamento e não sei o como implementar um SELECT em todos os tasks que não sejam o top 5 do dia.

Como faço para implementar isso no mysql?

Por exemplo, tenho um SELECT * FROM schedules aqui :
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Quero selecionar todos depois do 5, mas sem depender do Schedule_id porque ele pode variar muito no uso real do programa.

Comment: Seria interessante você informar a estrutura das tabelas que você usa para chegar no top 5

Comment: Obrigado pela dica, vou editar agora para incluir ele

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Achei uma [pergunta similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9116436/select-all-except-top-n-in-mysql) em inglês.

Resolvi da seguinte forma seguindo o que estava escrito.

```
SELECT * FROM Schedules WHERE Schedule_id NOT IN (
    SELECT Schedule_id FROM (
        SELECT Schedule_id FROM Schedules ORDER BY Schedule_id Limit 5
    ) AS x
)
```

Comment: Você pode aceitar sua própria resposta se quiser também! Mas é melhor esperar alguma outra resposta melhor antes.